# Passing values of dyanmically generating input fields through ajax to php

Tags: javascript, php

I have a dynamically generating input field which generates another input field with the click on add button.

```
<div class="entry input-group col-md-12">
    <input class="form-control" name="fields[]" type="url" placeholder="Type URL" />
    <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button class="btn btn-success btn-add" type="button">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
        </button>
    </span>
</div>
```

The problem is I want to take the values of these input fields through Ajax but only the first input field value is getting passed?

```
<script>
 function launchAjax(){
    $.post{"submit.php",{
        url: $("[name='fields[]']").val(),
  },
   );
};
```

Don't know how to fix it and If I do get this fix I also don't know how to handle it in PHP.Thank you for helping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The  [jQuery attribute selector](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/attribute-selectors/) must follow the next rules

> - double quotes inside single quotes: $('a[rel="nofollow self"]')
> - single quotes inside double quotes: $("a[rel='nofollow self']")
> - escaped  single quotes inside single quotes: $('a[rel=\'nofollow self\']')
> - escaped double quotes inside double quotes:  $("a[rel=\"nofollow self\"]")

In the previous jQuery versions, the selector works without quotes ( more details - https://github.com/jquery/jquery/issues/2824 )

fix for your issue ( just add quotes)

```
1) $("[name=\"fields[]\"]")
2) $('[name=\'fields[]\']')
3) $("[name='fields[]']");
4) $('[name="fields[]"]"');
```

Comment: I added the quotes but it's passing the value of the first input element only

Comment: You can refer to all of them by index $("[name='fields[]']").get(0) is the first , the second is $("[name='fields[]']").get(1)

Comment: You can get the  value of the last element using this : $("[name='fields[]']").last().val()

Comment: Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

**You need to wrap that selector with quotes:** `[name='fields[]']`

```js
console.log($("[name='fields[]']").val())
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input name="fields[]" value="Ele from SO">
```

Comment: but it's still passing the value of the very first input element not the second?